# Work to assemble charge distributions in the presence of a dielectric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential-energy, dielectric

I am asked by a problem to:

> Find the potential energy of a point charge in vacuum a distance $x$ away from a semi-infinite dielectric medium whose dielectric constant is $K$.

I wish to approach this problem by calculating the difference in the energy stored in the electric field of the configuration before and after the free-charge is moved into position using:

\begin{equation}
W = \frac{1}{2}\int_{V}\vec{E}\cdot\vec{D}\;dV
\end{equation}

I am thinking that if I take $W_1$ to be the energy stored in the field of the free-charge alone in free space, and then I take $W_2$ to be the energy stored in the free-charge/bound-polarization-charge field (after it has been moved a distance $x$ away from the dielectric medium), then the change in the energy I am looking for should be just

\begin{equation}
W = W_2 - W_1,
\end{equation}

and this will represent the potential energy of the free-charge.
However, I tried this approach and I don't think it works because I am somehow not taking into consideration the energy required to assemble the polarization-charge. Is it possible to approach this problem this way, and if so, then in general how do I take into consideration the energy required to assemble the polarization charge?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this approach is more difficult than I first thought because the sheet of polarized charge induced on the sheet has a complicated (?) E-field away from the surface since $\sigma_p$ is not uniform on the sheet. Considering this, perhaps it is better to solve this problem using the symmetries of the geometry instead of the stored-field energy. Considering this realization, I think that the direct calculation I've tried should work and that I initially mis-calculated the E-fields I used.